# Loading Colored Fonts With FreeType

Tags: c++, fonts, emoji, freetype

I'm trying to render emoticons that are already colored by default in the file.
I'm using 'Segoe UI Emoji' `SHA-256: 9e5a8c7e6c1e9096918a490798f4177107f0522870c8ad0227d5f02be407e0ed`

The problem is that `FT_HAS_COLOR()` always returns false, so therefor I can't use FT_LOAD_COLOR to load the bitmap to my texture.

I've opened the file in Universal Character Map and saw this -
[image: Segoe UI Emoji]

Heres a snippet from the code that rasterizes the glyphs

```
FT_Int32 flags = FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT | ( m_bAntiAliasing ? FT_LOAD_TARGET_NORMAL : FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO );
if ( FT_HAS_COLOR( m_face ) )
    flags |= FT_LOAD_COLOR;
else
    flags |= FT_LOAD_RENDER;         

if ( FT_Load_Char( m_face, glyphit->first, flags ) )
    continue;
```

Results in this
[image: result]

I would appreciate any help, I've been stuck on this for quite a while and have tried different versions of this font / other fonts.

Note: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368673/how-can-i-render-colored-glyphs-from-segoe-ui-emoji-with-freetype) but it doesn't seem like it was answered

Thank you.

Comment: if you're looking for an emoji font that does use color bitmaps then you could use emojione-android

Comment: I’ve tried, FT_Set_Char_Size fails with FT_Err_Invalid_Pixel_Size every time, and the bitmap is never filled.

Comment: with bitmaps you need to set one of the advertised sizes with `FT_Select_Size(face, 0);` for example. The second argument is an index available sizes that are listed in the array `available_sizes`

Comment: Do you have an example that renders color emojis with Freetype/pango, not just a snippet?

Comment: 2 years later, I am coming here because I am having the same issue with the exact same font file. While Noto Color Emoji works just fine (because of embedded bitmaps), I'd like to also support Segoe UI Emoji, that is using COLR/CPAL tables instead. Did you succeed and do you have anything that is publically sharable? :)

Answer (score 2):

From the FreeType docs:

> [Since 2.5] Load embedded **color bitmap images**. The resulting color bitmaps, if available, will have the FT_PIXEL_MODE_BGRA format. If the flag is not set and color bitmaps are found, they are converted to 256-level gray bitmaps transparently, using the FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY format.

Apparently FreeType only supports color bitmap images. Segoe uses the COLR/CPAL vector format, maybe that's why it's returning a negative and rendering the regular "black and white" glyphs?

Comment: This is partially true, starting with freetype 2.10 there's actually CPAL support and it should work the same way

Comment: See [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/include/freetype/freetype.h?id=0ac6921109aa78a26b874ad3a89b6ea0a209a7fc#n2971) it seems 2.10 is not tagged yet, so checkout out the development branch seems necessary for now

Comment: So it’s supported in 2.10, just not the 2.9.1 version that I’m using?

Comment: @Mike yes, 2.10 supports rendering the color font format used by `Segoe UI Emoji`, I tested it and it works

Answer (score 1):

Solved, @PeterT mentioned that FreeType 2.10 supports Segoe UI Emoji and similar fonts that use CPAL, 2.9.1 does not.

Thanks!